# String inside string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, string

I have noticed very weirdly behavior in javascript when assigning a string consist of two words to CSS property, what I set fontFamily property of an HTML element to value like `"Arial Black"` I end up with a string like this `"\"Arial Black\""` , I could not find any logical explanation to this behavior.

this is the code I run in the console.

```
element.style.fontFamily = "Arial Black"
>> "Arial Black"
element.style.fontFamily
>> "\"Arial Black\""
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

thank you for your time.

Comment: Interesting, couldn't understand your question/issue completely but have you tried putting the text inside of single quotes? `'Arial Black'`

Comment: Yes, I have but It doesn't work, I found what I want so thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font family names containing whitespace should be quoted. Your browser automatically adds the quotes for you, so retrieving them returns them with quotes. The following demo illustrates this:

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
one.style.fontFamily = "Helvetica";
console.log(one.style.fontFamily);
var two = document.getElementById("two");
two.style.fontFamily = "name with spaces";
console.log(two.style.fontFamily);
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```